# Not able to Enable postfix for outbound relay via Gmail on Mavericks

Tags: macos, email, terminal, bots

I am trying to enable postfix for outbond relay via gmail

I am following all the steps [from this site](http://slashusr.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/enabling-postfix-for-outbound-relay-via-gmail-on-os-x-lion-11/).

But not able to receive mail.

And got the following msg in file located at  `/var/mail`

```
host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.129.27] said:
550-5.7.1 [106.78.175.213] The IP you're using to send mail is not
authorized to 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the
SMTP relay at your 550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at 550
5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=10336
j5si48631733pbs.31 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

Actually I am integrating bot and want to receive mail on success or failure. But not receiving any mail so I googled and found that I have to enable postfix for outbound.

I have also try with `mailx <my gmail address>`  on terminal but didn't receive any email.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to shed some light on some fun I've had in a similar situation.  I have the Server 3.0 installed however so where things live can get irritating to track down.

In my situation postfix is running /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix.  But its moved around from release to release which makes your old configuration start to clutter up your build.

Within your postfix, you should have a main.cf.

I added a section:

```
>sudo nano main.cf
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks
reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_use_pw_server = yes
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
smtpd_pw_server_security_options = cram-md5,digest-md5,gssapi,login,plain
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/saslpasswd
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
```

CTL + O, enter to save

Its important to note now we have to deal with this /etc/postfix/saslpasswd

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/saslpasswd
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    first.last@gmail.com:YourPassword*9
```

CTL+O, enter to save.

There are a couple more commands to issue that I didn't find obvious.

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/saslpasswd
sudo postfix reload
```

Hope that helps.  The Base Mail / Server with the pretty on/off button doesn't seem to do that lat part for you.  And I reset my password from time to time.  When I do, I have to remember these paths, then make sure I issue those last two commands or the saslpasswd.db gets out of sync.

Good Luck